# Turn on relay when voltage larger then 13v

Tags: voltage, diodes, relay

I want to build circuit that turns on relay when voltage larger then 13 volts and turns relay off at 12 volts or lower  .I would like to use 12 or 5V relay

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ... and is this a repeat of a previous question switching from the 220V mains to a 12V battery (which goes up to 13V on charge) for a TV?

Comment: 5 V relay with a 10 V zener in series comes to mind.

Comment: My question is how to build something like this .No this is not switching 220v to 12v

Comment: Can you link me which zener diode you whould use ?

Comment: Depends on the relay. I assumed it would turn on at 3 V if it's rated for 5 V. Check the coil current if the relay and choose a zener diode which can take that current. Poor mans comparator. tcrosleys suggestion is more precise if you need exactly 13.0 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an inverting comparator with hysteresis.  This configuration is explained in this ["Comparator with Hysteresis Reference Design"](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf) application note.

[image]

The resistor values are calculated as follows (using the equations in the ap note, example on page 7).

A voltage divider made up of R1 (33.2k) and R2 (11k) is used to divide the input voltage by about 4, so it fits within the range of the comparator input.  13v => 3.23 (Vh), and 12v => 2.98v (Vl).

\$\frac{Rh}{Rx} = \frac{Vl} {Vh - Vl} = \frac{2.98} {3.23 - 2.98} = 11.92\$

\$\frac{Ry}{Rx} = \frac{Vl} {Vcc - Vh} = \frac{2.98} {5 - 3.23} = 1.68\$

\$Rh = 11.92 \times Rx\$

\$let\,Rx = 10k\$

\$Rh = 119.2k; \,closest\,1\%\,value\,is\,118k\$

\$Ry = 1.68 \times Rx\$

\$Ry = 16.8k; \,closest\,1\%\,value\,is\,16.9k\$

The inverting output of the comparator can be used to drive the input of a P-channel MOSFET hi-side switch, which will invert the signal a second time.  When Vin goes above 13v, the comparator will turn off, turning on the MOSFET and the relay.  When Vin falls below 12v, the comparator will turn on, turning off the MOSFET and the relay.